# Keras : Classification over time

Tags: keras, shapes, lstm

I try to classify the state of my system over the time.

I have 100 training samples containing over 1218 timesteps  33 inputs parameters.

So I have X_train.shape = [100, 1218, 33].

I use the Deep Learning library Keras to predict the output Y = 0 or 1.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1218 , 33), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation = 'softmax')))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Unfortunately I have the following error that I don't know how to resolve:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_3 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 1)

Does someone knows how to fix this ?

Regards.

Comment: Do you have a target value for each timestep or only one target for the whole sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model you provided expects a target for each timestep of a sequence. If you have only one target for the whole sequence (and the shape of the targets in the error message suggests that), you need to modify the model in the following way: Set `return_sequences` to `false` and remove the `TimeDistributed` wrapper:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1218 , 33), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I was very tired since I didn't notice the error was about the target and not about the input. I'll try it tomorrow.